# How can I snap two vertices of different objects while rotating?

Tags: objects, vertices, snapping

What I want to do is to **snap** vertex "**A**" of **selected object** to vertex "**B**" of an **other object**, while **rotating**. Any idea how can I do this?

[image]

Comment: You can snap while rotating, but unless vertex B is exactly on vertex A axis of rotation they will not exactly meet up. Try setting your "Snap With" setting to "Active" and make sure vertex A is the active vertex.

Comment: Do you mean to set "Pivot Point" to "Active Element" and then set active the "A" vertex? If yes, I have already done this... The "problem" is how to snap "A" with "B" while rotating.

Comment: No, set "Snap With" in snapping settings to Active, then with vertex A active try the rotation and and hover mouse over B.

Comment: Doesn't work... :(

Comment: have you tried?
create a vertex group for each one? And add, 2 empty for each, and add 2 hook modifier?

Comment: In some way I understand what you are saying, but I am not so expert on Blender so to implement all this... I don't know what vertex groups is for and hook modifier too!!! Can I have an example or farther explanation please?

Comment: yes...Vertex groups: They are groups created with only certain vertices of the mesh... So that you can use it in modifiers, constraint, cloth ... Without changing the other vertices... https://prnt.sc/xyv9d1

Comment: hook is a modifier ... and its name already explains its function... but it is necessary to have a separate "object" in this case here I used the empty. https://prnt.sc/xyvn9k https://prnt.sc/xyvvf1